# Pre-fill a Django ChoiceField inside a formset

Tags: django, formset

I have a formset with a `Runner` field that should have some value from a `Runner` model.
I use [select2](https://select2.org/) widget to fill this value: when user types something, I use Ajax to query appropriate rows from the database.

I want now to keep the values that this field stores when I submit my formset in case that there is some error and I have to show this form again.

If I define this field as `ChoiceField` with `choices=[]`, open the form and select some `runner` (e.g. with `id`=123), then after I send a POST request and try to initialize my formset with `FormsetResult(data=request.POST)`, I get an error that the value provided is not presented in the `choices` list which is true.

I tried to add this value to `choices` in the form constructor:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  runner_id = None
  if self.fields['runner'].initial:
    runner_id = kwargs['initial'].get('runner')
    runner = models.Runner.objects.filter(pk=runner_id).first()
    if runner:
      self.fields['runner'].choices = [('', ''), (runner_id, runner.get_name())]
```

, but this still doesn't work after I submit the form: `initial` values are now empty, and in case of formsets, `POST` dictionary has ugly field names like `form-0-runner` which makes it hard to extract the value that I need.

Another option is to write some hack in the template that will load from the DB the value I need:

```
<select name="form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-runner" id="id_form-{{ forloop.counter0 }}-runner">
    {% if form.instance.runner %}
        <option value="{{ form.instance.runner.id }}" selected>{{ form.instance.runner.get_name }}</option>
    {% endif %}
</select>
```

, but this isn't beautiful either.

Maybe you can see a better way to achieve this?
Maybe [Django-Select2](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) app will help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the `__init__` method in your form

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #if form input is empty
    self.fields['runner'].queryset = Runner.objects.none()

    # if user typed something
    if 'runner' in self.data:
        self.fields['runner'].queryset = Runner.objects.all()

    # if object exists it will set the value of field to previously saved one
    elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['runner'].queryset = Runner.objects.all().filter(pk=self.instance.runner.pk)
```